# Whatsapp API php code request

Tags: php, whatsapp

Following is my code to CodeRequest.

```
$username = "91xxxxxxxxxx";   
$identity = strtolower(urlencode(sha1($username, true)));
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, "test", true);
$r = $w->codeRequest();

print_r($r);
```

It gives the response as

```
stdClass Object ( [status] => sent [length] => 6 [method] => sms [retry_after] => 1805 )
```

But I'm not receiving message. Any suggestions please.

My other questions.

1. Is there any restriction to request code.(Every time I use new mobile number).?
2. For example I request a code for mobile number `xxx` with user agent `galaxys3` shall i request another code with mobile number `yyy` using the same user agent?

I'm using [WhatsAPI-Official](https://github.com/mgp25/WhatsAPI-Official)

Comment: can u tell me how u get password from whatsapp..i mean in windows os in which way we can get pwd of whatsapp...

Comment: Once you get the confirmation/verification code using `codeRegister(verificationcode)` function you can get the password.

Comment: i'm using the same api u used..when i run whatsapp.php inside example folder i'm getting error like **Parse error: parse error in G:\wamp\www\WhatsAPI\src\WhatsAppEvent.php on line 105**...i'm not sure which file i have to run first

Comment: OK.. you have to run `exampleRegister.php` file in examples folder change your username, identity and nick.

Comment: how u get `identity` variable's value..

Comment: Just simply u can use it as `$identity = "myIdentity";` that's it. Remaining thing api will take care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65571/discussion-between-jivani-jaydeep-and-gowri).

Comment: @Gowri https://github.com/shirioko/WART easy to get password and id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I received code to mobile.

```
$username = "91xxxxxxxxxx";   
$identity = "myIdentity";
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, "test", true);
$r = $w->codeRequest('sms',$carrier); 
(or)
$r = $w->codeRequest('voice',$carrier);   //Voice service is fast compared to sms
```

`$carrier` is getting from `networkinfo.csv` file.

carrier is nothing but mobile network operator(Airtel,Idea etc.,) according to your mobile country code(mcc) and mobile network code (mnc).

You can get the mnc and mcc codes from [mobile-network-codes-country-codes](http://mcclist.com/mobile-network-codes-country-codes.asp)

Get mcc and mnc codes with your location and operation match them with `networkinfo.csv` to get `carrier` name.

```
Eg: My number is 919xxxxxx
    country -  india ( Andhra Pradesh )
    operator - Idea
```

For above link mcc and mnc are for my number is `404 &  7`

Now check those codes in `networkinfo.csv` file

i.e 
`404,1028,007,7,in,India,91,Idea Cellular Ltd.4`

Here `404 -> mcc` 
and  `007 -> mnc`

My carrier name is `Idea Cellular Ltd.4`

If you send correct carrier name you will get sms/call to mobile.

Comment: How do you obtain $identity? Do this works? => strtolower(urlencode(sha1($username, true)));

Comment: I gave static text for identity like `$identity = "myIdentity"`.
Previously I used `urlencode` method but it won't work for me.

Comment: @Gowri Can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983239/how-to-send-message-using-whatsapp-api

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.

```
    $destinationPhone = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $w = new WhatsProt($userPhone, $userIdentity, $userName, $debug);
    $w->Connect();
    $w->LoginWithPassword($password);
    $w->Message($destinationPhone, $argv[1]);
```

or more info refer this link..
http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/#Send-WhatsApp-messages

Comment: I'm asking about requesting code not send messages.