# How to send message using whatsapp API

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am newer to implement whatsApp API in my project and I downloaded [whatsapp API](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI). I used ajaxDemo from that and set following code in my file but it is not working and give `internal error` in `socket.php` file.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["running"] = time();
$_SESSION["inbound"] = array();
$_SESSION["outbound"] = array();
$target = "+91**********"; //conversation target number/JID
?>
```

**socket.php**

```
require_once '../whatsprot.class.php';  //I got error this two lines
$target = @$_POST["target"];
$username = "+91**********";  //My whatsapp account number
$password = "*********";  //static password
$w = new WhatsProt($username, 0, "WhatsApi AJAX Demo", true);

$w->eventManager()->bind("onGetImage", "onGetImage");
$w->eventManager()->bind("onGetProfilePicture", "onGetProfilePicture");

$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
```

I think there is any connection problem with `socket.php` file.

Please point out me where actually problem in my code?

Comment: If you need more code or any suggestion then let me know I will update my question.

Comment: That's not an official API...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [github issue](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/528) for help

I'm in the same process my self but it work for me

on file index.php :

```
$target = "+91**********"; //phone number to send sms to-
```

on file socket.php :

```
$username = "+91**********";  //Your whatsapp account number 
$password = "L2gc4b1ztgbfR/bEoPrP10gqQyE=";  //static password
```

static password is the password that you get running the exampleRegister.php yours should be different and every time you connect it will change and along with it your account on phone will be verified again.

trying to work around that and do something more like https://web.whatsapp.com/ does..